# Data Structure and Design for Java object model based on Aggregating Data

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, cyclic-graph

Am working on a coding exercise which I am somewhat confused on how to implement a solution.

According to the JavaDoc, I have to implement this EmployeeManager interface. Presume that employee data arrives in a separate thread from other requests. Note that getSalary() execute in constant time O(n). Execution time must not vary with number of employees or departments.

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Manage departments and employees to easily query aggregate data.
 * All methods should be thread-safe.
 */
public interface EmployeeManager {

    /**
     * Create a new department with the given name and the given parentId. 
     * The department name need not be unique.
     * 
     * @param departmentName
     *            the name of the new department.
     * @param parentId
     *            the parent department or null if no parent
     * @return the ID of the newly created department
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if the parent department (if not null) does not exist
     */
    public int newDepartment(String departmentName, Integer parentDepartmentId);

    /**
     * Create a new employee with the given ID 
     * and given parent department (if any).
     * 
     * @param employeeId
     *            the new employee's ID
     * @param parentdepartmentId
     *            the parent department or null if no parent
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if the employee or parent department (if not null) does not exist
     */
    public void newEmployee(int employeeId, Integer parentdepartmentId);

    /**
     * Return a list of department IDs that are 
     * direct children of the given parent. 
     * 
     * Null is a valid value for parent.
     * 
     * @param departmentId
     *            the parent department ID
     * @return a list of child department IDs
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if the department does not exist
     */
    public List<Integer> getDepartments(Integer departmentId);

    /**
     * Return a list of employee IDs that are direct children of the given parent. 
     * Null is a valid value for parent.
     * 
     * @param departmentId
     *            the parent department ID
     * @return a list of child employee IDs
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if the department does not exist
     */
    public List<Integer> getEmployees(Integer departmentId);

    /**
     * Move the given department to the new parent.
     * 
     * @param departmentId
     *            the ID of the department to move
     * @param parentDepartmentId
     *            the new parent. The new parent department 
     *            -- if the id is not null -- must exist, and
     *            must not create a cyclic graph.
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if a cyclic graph would be created or
     *             the department or parent department does not exist
     */
    public void moveDepartment(int departmentId, Integer parentDepartmentId);

    /**
     * Move the given employee to the new parent.
     * 
     * @param employeeId
     *            the ID of the employee to move
     * @param parentDepartmentId
     *            the new parent. The new parent department 
     *            -- if the id is not null -- must exist.
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if the employee or parent department 
     *             (if not null) does not exist
     */
    public void moveEmployee(int employeeId, Integer parentDepartmentId);

    /**
     * Return the name of the given department.
     * 
     * @param departmentId
     *            the department ID
     * @return the department name
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if the department does not exist
     */
    public String getName(int departmentId);

    /**
     * Return the current aggregate salaries of 
     * all employees in the given department
     * 
     * (including all employees in all child departments).
     * 
     * Must execute in constant time O(n).
     * 
     * @param departmentId
     *            the department ID
     * @return the aggregate salary or return null if no employees
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if the department does not exist
     */
    public Double getSalary(int departmentId);

    /**
     * New data has arrived from the given employee. 
     * If new data arrives for an unknown employee, then
     * create this employee with parent department null.
     * 
     * @param employeeId
     *            the employee ID
     * @param salary
     *            the new salary
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             if the employee does not exist
     */
    public void newEmployeeData(int employeeId, double salary);
}
```

Question(s):

1. What type of problem is this?
2. Should I create Employee and Department classes as POJOs and what would be inside? Will they have to implement runnable in order to be thread-safe?
3. What type of data structure(s) does this need?

Am really rusty with my data structures and CS stuff so would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seriously, though... Does anyone know how to design the object model? Any data structures or design patterns?

Comment: Is this question better suited for the Code Review forum of Stack Exchange?

Comment: No, there isn't any working code included in the question, which would make it off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: That said, I don't think that asking for advice about how to approach an exercise is suitable for Stack Overflow either, as it is too broad. You would be better off completing the exercise yourself, then posting your solution as a question on Code Review.

Comment: 200_success Thanks for responding... I just don't know which data structures to use. Does anyone see a pattern for a specific design that this question is alluding to?